# Should I make the object mutable?

Tags: java, design-patterns, immutability

I have a `service A` which listens for messages from a Queue and calls another `service B` to get some values assume val1...x.

Assuming my entity is

```
Entity
|- val1
|- val2
|
... val1n
```

The values from both the `service B` populates assume `x` vals in the entity.
And after the service call `service A` computes some values and populates other fields in the entity.

Possible approaches for modeling the `Entity`

[1] Make Entity immutable and make every update to the entity copy all values 1...x to make a new object.

[2] Make Entity partially immutable like declaring val1...x final and others non-final, so I can use `setters` to set the values on them.

EDIT : [3] Keep passing around Builder Object and when all values val1...n has been populated call the build() function.

EDIT2 : [4] Have two separate object (private inner) immutable - val1...x and immutable valx..n. Everytime some update happens on the valx..n I will create new copy of mutable object and refer to the immutable one.

Comment: approach 2 would be suitable, you should try to make all fields mutable that can cause you object to be in-stable during the execution. But not necessarily all the fields. But it is often advised to make your entity mutable as possible because you may not anticipate any possible causes that some 3 third party could modify your object and leave it un-stable

Comment: Two different threads, two different fields then why immutable?

Comment: @SMA probably because of bias of reading pros of immutable objects like thread-safety etc. I am wondering when should we give away immutability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are willing to create object in one service, populate some of the fields, than pass it to another service, and populate rest of them? After this, the object is complete?

If so, I would use **Builder** patter, populating fields of builer and once it's complete - build immutable object

Comment: Assume I created an `Entity object` during service call. Now when I populate other fields, I have to copy all the previous fields `val 1...x` in my new builder object. This is my approach `1`

Answer (score 1):

Make `service B` return an immutable value object (let's call it `ExtendedEntityInformation`), then use the values from `service A` and that object to create your immutable `Entity`. You might even just store the `ExtendedEntityInformation` object in your `Entity` and if needed, implement getters on `Entity` that delegate to getters in `ExtendedEntityInformation`.